# Triggering of HTTP request

Tags: html, httprequest

HTML:

```
<div style="display: none";><img src="mypic.jpg" alt="Photo"></div>
```

Does the HTML above trigger a http request when the page first loads?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. Specifically, `<img src="example.jpg">` triggers an [HTTP GET request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/GET) to retrieve the content located at `example.jpg`. If the URL is [relative](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/What_is_a_URL#Absolute_URLs_vs_relative_URLs) (such as `example.jpg`, `/example.jpg`, or `../example.jpg`), it is resolved relative to the current page.

You can view HTTP requests in browser developer tools. For example, in Chrome:

1. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> to open dev tools (Mac: <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>).
2. Navigate to the "Network" tab.
3. Reload the page (<kbd>F5</kbd>) to see all the HTTP requests made on page load.